# How to pass seccond value to scrapy crawler in python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am pass a second variable (ID) to my scrapy crawler. As a python beginner I am kind of stuck here. How could that be done? This is my code:

Get all needed values (ID, URL):

```
# SQL pseudo code: get values:
SELECT
    ID,
    URL
...
```

Append all URLs to  start_urls. I understand that row[0] would be the ID, but how to associate it with the URL?

```
results = curb.fetchall()
for row in results: start_urls.append(row[1])
```

Start requests with the URLs, I would need to pass the ID along with the coresponding URL, so I can access it later in the code with self.ID.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:

        if validators.url(url):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                # ID=ID,
                url=url,
                meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]},
                callback=self.parse_item,
            )
        else:
            print("Invalid URL ", format(url))
```

Comment: maybe run `fetchall()` inside `start_requests()` and then you can use `meta={"id": ID, ...}` in `Request` to send this value to `parse_item`. And inside `def parse_item(response)` you can get `ID = response.meta["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it inside `start_requests()` and then you can use `meta={'id': ID, ...}` in `Request()` to send this value to `parse_item()`

```
def start_requests(self):

    results = curb.fetchall()

    #for url in self.start_urls:
    for row in results:
        url = row[0]
        ID = row[1] 

        if validators.url(url):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                meta={'ID': ID, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]},
                callback=self.parse_item,
            )
        else:
            print("Invalid URL ", format(url))
```

And later you can get it in `parse_item()`

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    ID = reponse.meta['ID']
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't have other urls in `start_urls` then you can even use it for this. You can keep `rows` in  `start_urls`

```
results = curb.fetchall()
for row in results: 
     start_urls.append(row)

def start_requests(self):

    #for row in results:
    for row in self.start_urls:
        url = row[0]
        ID = row[1] 

        if validators.url(url):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                meta={'ID': ID, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]},
                callback=self.parse_item,
            )
        else:
            print("Invalid URL ", format(url))
```

You could even directly assign it

```
 start_urls = curb.fetchall()

 def start_requests(self):
     
    for row in self.start_urls:
        url = row[0]
        ID = row[1] 

        # ... code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be added in the `meta` parameter.

```
def start_requests(self):
for url in self.start_urls:

    if validators.url(url):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            # ID=ID,
            url=url,
            meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]}, <<<< Add ID here.
            callback=self.parse_item,
        )
    else:
        print("Invalid URL ", format(url))
```

The right way is:

```
def start_requests(self):
for url in self.start_urls:

    if validators.url(url):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            meta={'ID': ID, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]},
            callback=self.parse_item,
        )
    else:
        print("Invalid URL ", format(url))
```